# Is there a way so that returning from the base virtual method would affect override too?

Tags: c#

Here's a quick example of what I mean:

```
//Base class
public virtual void Equip(Item item) {
    if (item == null) return;
    SetItem(item);
}

//Interited class
public override void Equip(Item item) {
    base.Equip(item);
    //returning doesn't work. I have to rewrite all of my conditions or there's better approach?
    someList.Add(item);
}
```

So basically, my question is, when you call base virtual method, you're calling it like any other function and it doesn't affect the override method whatsoever? And there is no other way of returning from a function aside from rewriting all of my ifs?

Comment: yes, calling base function is the same as calling any other function, return from base just return to overriden one

Comment: Your comment is ambiguous, base it setting the item for you, but what were you expecting. What are all of your conditions and why do you think you don't need to set them.

Comment: Please include the class structure, this looks like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/), something else in your inheritance does not look right.

Comment: You should avoid early breaking logic like this, if there is a condition to exclude certain elements then you should change the method returns type to something meaningful, then you could easily chain the logic. Using return like that is a glorified GOTO statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can split the base class method in two, and only allow the overridden behaviour once validation is complete:

```
//Base class
public void Equip(Item item) {
    if (item == null) return;
    EquipOnceValidated(item);
}

protected virtual void EquipOnceValidated(Item item) {
    SetItem(item);
}

//Interited class
protected override void EquipOnceValidated(Item item) {
    //Decide if we still want to call the base class method or not
    someList.Add(item);
}
```